# Organizing Dynamically Created Objects in Unity Editor

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-editor

I'm dynamically creating buttons and sprites in my Unity project (for reasons). I'm making a lot of them. I know that it doesn't matter on compiled code, but while I'm debugging my code in the unity editor, this creates a massive unsorted list of objects with similar names (I *have* named them for clarity, but there's a lot of similarity).

When I'm creating stuff in the editor, I'm able to group it into groups and subgroups for easy organization.

Is there a way to put the dynamically created objects into groups so that the unity editor will group them for easy browsing while I'm debugging?
(Unity Level: Learning, C# Level: Experienced)

Comment: What do you mean by "groups"? Do you mean just making all of your dynamically created objects children of the same parent? For example, if you're dynamically making a bunch of Card GameObjects, you can put them all as children for a Deck GameObject.

Comment: Or, if you're just wanting to see all of a specifc type of GameObject you created where they have similar names, you can use the search box at the top of the Hierarchy Window.

Comment: Yes, how would I make them as children for a Deck GameObject? Is there a way to grab that by name in the code? Or do I need to pass it on to my script? Can I make that dynamically?

Comment: You can either have a placeholder object that you create in the editor, and then pass that Parent GameObject as a parameter into the script that you're using to dynamically create  your other GameObjects, and then just call ```transform.SetParent(yourParentTransform)``` ------ Or you can also dynamically create your parent from code just like your other gameobjects if you'd rather the entirety of it be done from code.

Comment: You can also have the parent be set when you instantiate your objects as well, using ```UnityEngine.Object.Instantiate(prefab, position, rotation, parentTransform);```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an empty parent object before instantiating your buttons etc.

```
// This will create an empty GameObject.
var parentObj = new GameObject("Parent Object");

for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    Instantiate(prefab, transform.position, Quaternion.identity, parentObj.transform);
```

Comment: @JKreft you would pass in the Transform of your parent, not the entire GameObject. ```parentGameObject.transform```

Answer (score 0):

if you are referring to grouping things within your script, you can use `public List<GameObject> objects;` if you get creative with this you can sort your list in all sorts of ways. If you are refering to the scenes heirarchy within the editor, you can, when instantiating your gameObjects change their parent, so they can be grouped under empties. If that's what you were looking for.

```
cloneObject.transform.parent = desiredParentObjectTransform;
```